# Is go passing variable by reference?

Tags: pointers, go

I am trying to understand some go code. I have provided a runnable example and output. The output is printing the value 10 for every defer function that gets called. I would have expected incrementing values to be returned. If I don't call the `print` from a function it works as expected.

Is go passing `i` by reference (not by value) and since defer runs at the end of a function life cycle `i` is effectively 10 in memory so it prints 10? I couldn't find anything to explain what is exactly happening here.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("counting")

    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        defer func() {fmt.Println(i)}()
    }

    fmt.Println("done")
}
```

Output

```
counting
done
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
```

Comment: Essentially the same as https://golang.org/doc/faq#closures_and_goroutines

Comment: You'll also see that `go vet` will flag this, so any test of this code would fail.

Comment: Note that `i` is not *passed* at all: it's *inherited* via closure. Inheritance like this is equivalent to Algol's pass-by-name, though, so if you want to equate it to argument passing, it's neither by-reference nor by-value, but by-name.